# SQL2008 Integration Services - Loading CSV files with varying file schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, ssis

I'm using SQL2008 to load sensor data in a table with Integration Services.  I have to deal with hundreds of files. The problem is that the CSV files all have slightly different schemas.  Each file can have a maximum of 20 data fields. All data files have these fields in common. Some files have all the fields others have some of the fields.  In addition, the order of the fields can vary.

Here’s and example of what the file schemas look like.
Station Name,Station ID,LOCAL_DATE,T_1,TD_1,RH_1,CL_1,RS_1,RI_1,PR_1,RD_1,SH_1,CL_2
Station Name,Station ID,LOCAL_DATE,T_1,TD_1,RH_1,CL_1,RS_1,RI_1,PR_1,WS_1,WD_1,WSM_1,WDM_1,SH_1
Station Name,Station ID,LOCAL_DATE,T_1,TD_1,RH_1,RS_1,RI_1,PR_1,RD_1,WS_1,WD_1,WSM_1,WDM_1
Station Name,Station ID,LOCAL_DATE,T_1,RH_1,RS_1,PR_1,VI_1,PW_1,WS_1,WD_1,WSM_1
Station Name,Station ID,LOCAL_DATE,T_1,RH_1,RS_1,WS_1,WD_1,WSM_1
Station Name,Station ID,LOCAL_DATE,T_1,RH_1,RS_1,PR_1,VI_1,WS_1,WD_1,WSM_1

I’m using a Data Flow Script Task  to process the data via CreateNewOutputRows() and MyOutputBuffer.AddRow().  I have a working package to load the data however it’s not reliable and robust because as I had more files the package fails because the file schema has not been defined in CreateNewOutputRows().

I'm looking for a dynamic solution that can cope with the variation in the file schema. Doeas anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Who controls the data model for the output of the sensors?   If it's not you, do they know what they are doing?  If they create new and inconsistent models every time they invent a new sensor, you are pretty much up the creek.

If you can influence or control the evolution of the schemas for CSV files, try to come up with a top level data architecture.  In the bad old days before there were databases,  files made up of records often had, as the first field of each record, a "record type".  CSV files could be organized the same way.  The first field of every record could indicate what type of record you are dealing with.  When you get an unknown type, put it in the "bad input file" until you can maintain your software.

If that isn't dynamic enough for you, you may have to consider artificial intelligence, or looking for a different job.

Comment: The sensors have been installed over many years across a wide geographical area. There is a finite set of data items to deal with but these have been inconsistently setup on each sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the cmd command is good. in the cmd, you can use sqlserver import csv.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSV files that all have identical formats use the same file name convention or if they can be separated out in some fashion you can use the ForEach Loop Container for each file schema type.

Possible way to separate out the CSV files is run a Script (in VB) in SSIS that reads the first row of the CSV file and checks for the differing types (if the column names are in the first row) and then moves the files to the appropriate folder for use in the ForEach Loop Container.